# Is it possible to map the Bluetooth keyboard to the Android custom keyboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-keyboard, keymapping, android-custom-keyboard

I have implemented a custom keyboard using Android Studio (Input Method Service) with Kotlin. If I install this app on an Android device and connect a Bluetooth keyboard, is it possible to map the Bluetooth keyboard to the custom keyboard?

is it possible to map the Bluetooth keyboard to the Android custom keyboard?